# How to open popup from appdelegate?

Tags: swift, popup, appdelegate

I have some assignment to make and I am struggling. 
I have to open a modal popup at the start of an application but when I try to load my popup view my outlets are always nil, I tried a couple of different ways to load the view and its outlets are always nil.
Any suggestions?
Here I post some code

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        window?.rootViewController = FirstLaunchViewController()
   }
```

This is my appDelegate.

```
 class StartNavViewController: UINavigationController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    perform(#selector(showPopUp), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.01)

}

@objc func showPopUp(){

    let first = FirstLaunchViewController()

    present(first, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }

}
```

This is my starting navigation controller from which I am trying to load my FirstLaunchVC. I also tried preparing and performing a segue which resulted the exact same = outlets are nil.
In the FirstLaunchVC I set some values to my outlets in the viewdidload method, if needed I can post some code for more clarity.

I am fairly new to Swift so be as accurate as possible. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your vc is inside storyboard

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCID") as! FirstLaunchViewController 
window?.rootViewController = vc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: May God bless you sir! :) This is working just fine! Thanks!